# Stata related -selecting specific rows

Tags: extract, stata

I am currently working with a dataset that has information on individuals i = 1,...,N by time t = 1,...,T. I basically have a panel structure in my dataset. However, I want to select only one row of data from each individual. Specifically, I want to select *only* the last time period t=T for each individual i=1,...,N. How can I 'extract' this specific information from the bigger dataset?

Comment: I should emphasize that I am using STATA

Comment: I will emphasize you are using _Stata_ (although some users do not care much for the spelling). What you ask for is a mix of basic operations. See `help <command>`, where _<command>_ refers to `by`, `sort`, `gen`, `keep`, `drop`, `subscript`, and others.

Comment: The Stata FAQ: http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/first-and-last-occurrences/ should also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Stata [not STATA] rows are more properly called **observations**. You can "select" the last observation in each panel with the generic

```
bysort id (time) : ... if _n == _N
```

as under the aegis of `by:`

1. the built-in variable `_n` identifies observations in each panel
2. its sibling `_N` is the number of observations in each panel and therefore identifies the last observation in each panel.

This is well documented: e.g. see the help and manual entries explaining the `by:` prefix.